# Table of aggregated means in R

Tags: r, aggregate, frequency

I want to create a table of means for categorical data.

I can easily create a frequency table, for example:

```
ftable(xtabs(formula = ~ cyl + am, data = mtcars))

    am  0  1
cyl         
4       3  8
6       4  3
8      12  2
```

But instead of the number of elements at each category, I want to put the means (or other statistics) of each cell as in aggregate table:

```
aggregate(mtcars$mpg, by = list(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am), FUN = mean)

  Group.1 Group.2        x
1       4       0 22.90000
2       6       0 19.12500
3       8       0 15.05000
4       4       1 28.07500
5       6       1 20.56667
6       8       1 15.40000
```

Instead of a list as in aggregate table above, I want the means in table form as in frequency table.

In addition, I want to do this for a more complicated table, such as:

```
ftable(xtabs(formula = ~ cyl + am + carb , data = mtcars))

       carb 1 2 3 4 6 8
cyl am                 
4   0       1 2 0 0 0 0
    1       4 4 0 0 0 0
6   0       2 0 0 2 0 0
    1       0 0 0 2 1 0
8   0       0 4 3 5 0 0
    1       0 0 0 1 0 1
```

Creating such a table of means has an additional complication. Some cells does not have any elements, so the means of those cells should be `NA`.

Comment: Can you please show a desired output? it is not clear to me what is your final goal.

Comment: In the first frequency table, I simply want to put means instead of frequencies. So, in the cell (`am = 0`, `cyl = 8`) instead of `12`, I want a table that writes  the mean `15.05`.

Comment: I think I found it under the help of aggregate: `xtabs(x ~ ., data = aggregate(mtcars$mpg, by = list(cyl = mtcars$cyl, am = mtcars$am), FUN = mean))
`  and `ftable(xtabs(x ~ ., data = aggregate(mtcars$mpg, by = list(cyl = mtcars$cyl, am = mtcars$am, carb = mtcars$carb), FUN = mean)))` will do the trick for me.

Comment: Post it as a solution, they are very smart piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution under the help of `aggregate` function:

```
aggData1 <- aggregate(mtcars$mpg, 
                      by = list(cyl = mtcars$cyl, am = mtcars$am), 
                      FUN = mean)
xtabs(x ~ ., data = aggData1)

   am
cyl        0        1
  4 22.90000 28.07500
  6 19.12500 20.56667
  8 15.05000 15.40000
```

For three categorical variables:

```
aggData2 <- aggregate(mtcars$mpg, 
                      by = list(cyl = mtcars$cyl, am = mtcars$am, carb = mtcars$carb), 
                      FUN = mean)
ftable(xtabs(x ~ ., data = aggData2))

       carb     1     2     3     4     6     8
cyl am                                         
4   0       21.50 23.60  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
    1       29.10 27.05  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
6   0       19.75  0.00  0.00 18.50  0.00  0.00
    1        0.00  0.00  0.00 21.00 19.70  0.00
8   0        0.00 17.15 16.30 12.62  0.00  0.00
    1        0.00  0.00  0.00 15.80  0.00 15.00
```